# Add and remove options to a mount point without umount

Tags: mount

I have a gluster mount point with some issues, to find a file using its gfid I have to mount (remount) the gluster volume with an additional option.

mount -t glusterfs -o **aux-gfid-mount** hostname:volume-name  <path_to_fuse_mnt>

How can I add this option without disturbing the mount point and loosing its actual options, and how can I remove that option once I have completed my work?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the file system, and I don't know glusterfs well enough. But:

Some file systems support `-o remount` that allows for keeping all currently available, opened files the way they are but changes mount options

```
mount -t glusterfs -o remount,aux-gfid-mount hostname:volume-name
```

I remember (but I don't know if that's still the case with current kernels!) that ca 2016 (so, Linux 3.10 or so??), FUSE could **not** be remounted at all. So, you might simply are hoping to do something impossible if this is really a FUSE mount (and I think Glusterfs is a pure userspace filesystem, so yes, it is).

If glusterfs doesn't support remounting, then you're out of luck, and need to mount the same volume someplace else with the `aux-gfid-mount` option (mouting it `ro` might be a good choice for that!) and do your finding there (and unmount afterwards). That doesn't seem *that* bad an option, to be honest! (It feels strange to say "I want my file system to behave differently for some time, while it's in such active usage that I can't unmount it"; that feels like a bit of a bad idea.)

Comment: +1, but you shouldn't need to extract and re-use the old options.  `-o remount` won't change them unless a new option conflicts or requires them to be changed.   e.g. it's enough to do `mount -o rw,remount /mount-point` if all you want to do is change from Read-Only to Read/Write, all other mount options will remain as they were before the remount.

Comment: ah, interesting! Amended :)